# Result of boost::posix_time::milliseconds(0)

Tags: c++11, boost

What is the behaviour of boost::posix_time::milliseconds() function if value 0 is passed as argument to this function?

Comment: well, it's zero: https://ideone.com/ghwfhX what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

The function `boost::posix_time::milliseconds(long)` creates an object of type `time_duration` which represents a certain amount of time. `boost::posix_time::milliseconds(0)` will, therefore, represent a duration of `0` seconds.